# Tailwind CSS: when using justify-center and overflow-auto at the parent element, the first child does not fully show

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am currently working with tailwind to create a log in form.

The HTML looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <div class="w-full h-full flex flex-col p-5 md:flex-row md:space-x-2">
            <div class="w-full h-1/4 flex justify-center items-center md:w-1/2 md:h-full">
               
            </div>
            <div class="w-full h-3/4 p-2 md:w-1/2 md:h-full">
                <div class="h-10 flex justify-around items-center mb-1 space-x-2">
                    <a class="h-full w-full">
                        <div class="flex h-full w-full justify-center items-center text-center text-lg border rounded-lg border-red-900">
                            <span>Log in</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a class="h-full w-full">
                        <div class="flex h-full w-full justify-center items-center text-center text-lg border rounded-lg border-red-900">
                            <span class="">Sign up</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div style="height: calc(100% - 2.5rem) !important" class="p-2 border rounded-lg border-red-900 shadow-2xl">
                    <div class="w-full h-full flex relative">
                        <form class="w-full h-full">
                            <div style="height: calc(100% - 2.5rem) !important" class="w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center overflow-auto">
                                <div class="w-3/4 my-3 mx-auto flex flex-col justify-center">
                                    <label class="w-full">
                                        <span class="font-mono ml-3">Email</span>
                                        <input class="w-full px-3 border rounded-lg border-red-700 h-8 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-red-700 focus:z-10" type="text" 
                                        placeholder="user@mail.com" required autofocus>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="w-3/4 my-3 mx-auto flex flex-col justify-center">
                                    <label class="w-full">
                                        <span class="font-mono ml-3">Password</span>
                                        <input class="w-full px-3 border rounded-lg border-red-700 h-8 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-red-700 focus:z-10" type="password"
                                        placeholder="********" required>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="w-3/4 mx-auto text-right text-red-700">
                                    <a>Forgot password?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-red-700 m-auto h-10 w-3/4 absolute bottom-0 inset-x-0 text-center border rounded-lg">
                                <button class="font-mono h-full w-full focus:bg-red-700 focus:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 border rounded-lg border-red-700 hover:bg-red-700 hover:text-white"
                                type="submit">Log in</button> <!-- [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" -->
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>          
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**The problem**

As you can see, in the parent `div`, it contains the class `overflow-auto`. The issue is that when the overflow is activated, part of the first child is not shown for some reason. When removing the `justify-center` (also in the parent div) this issue is no longer a problem, however I want the content to be vertically centered.

Please see the following image to get a graphical idea. As the image shows, the scrollbar is at its top limit, however the first child is only partly displayed.

[image]

Comment: I've just added a snippet in your post and it looks OK. We probably need to see some more HTML to solve this.

Comment: Hi Zsolt, thanks for checking it out. I have updated the HTML and I made sure that the issue is visible as it is in the picture I uploaded. I had to remove the JS Fiddle thingy as it wasn't letting me properly change the mark up.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue you've described, using the Tailwind Playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/B0L59i6jr4. In general I'd try to remove all the `!important` inline styles like `style="height: calc(100% - 2.5rem) !important"`, as they're likely to have unexpected effects when you change around other parts of your styles.

Comment: The reason why I used the inline styles, is to keep it all to a single html file as this is part of an Angular app. I am able to replicate the issue by resizing the browser window rather than using Chrome's devices in the dev tools. Could you perhaps try that? Thanks in advance